# How do I insert/extract front matter from Blackfriday in Go?

Tags: go, markdown

In jekyll you insert this at the top of your markdown and are able to insert them into your layouts:

```
---

layout: post

title: Blogging Like a Hacker

---
```

I need to do the same in Go using no frameworks or fancy packages. Just Golang.

```
import (
       "github.com/russross/blackfriday"
       "html/template"
       "io/ioutil"
       "net/http"
)

type webPost struct {
     Title       string
     Author      string
     Description string
     Body        template.HTML
}



func handlePost(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

          //Read in some markdown from a file
          input, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("test.md")
          //Render it into HTML
          output := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon(input)

          //I need the first three parameters to grab the front matter from test.md
          post := webPost{"title", "author", "a descritpion", template.HTML(output)}
          //Serve to client a template 
          templates.ExecuteTemplate(res, "Post", post)
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does the dividing line between "fancy" and "non-fancy" packages lay?

Comment: For extraction, you'd need to parse the slice of bytes, extracting the YAML information, and pass the remaining bytes to `MarkdownCommon`. [A YAML parser](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2) could help here, if you didn't want to parse it yourself, though it might be overkill in your case.

Comment: You are already using a *fancy package* named blackfriday.  Also, `html/template`, `io/ioutil` and `net/http` are all *fancy packages* as well - just they are included with Go's installation.  Just use `github.com/go-yaml/yaml` and move on.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look into the yaml package. I just didn't want to use something huge like Hugo or Revel.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/gernest/front to parse jekyll files. Works pretty well. First parse the file with `front`, then pass body to blackfriday.